# Confusion over the ability to re-order a Dict or OrderedDict

Tags: python, flask

I am here because I have been struggling to re-order a Dict that I have created. In short I pass a list of tweets returned from Twitter API through a reducer to group them by hashtag, naturally I want to use Dict for this because it gives a convenient shape:

```
{
  "covid19": [tweet1,tweet2],
  "COVID": [tweet1,tweet2, Tweet3]
}
```

But unfortunately after I run sort over my Dict to order the hashtags with most tweets, the ordering does not change when I send it to the client, its actually alphabetically ordered for some reason.

```
# method called by reducer below to group posts by their first hashtag
def group_posts_by_hashtag(hashtag_group, post):
    first_hashtag_of_post = post['entities']['hashtags'][0]['text']
    hashtag_group[first_hashtag_of_post] = hashtag_group.get(first_hashtag_of_post, [])
    hashtag_group[first_hashtag_of_post].append(post)
    return hashtag_group

tweets_categorised_by_hashtag = reduce(group_posts_by_hashtag, tweets_with_hashtags, defaultdict(list))

# sort by most tweets per hashtag
sorted_hashtags = OrderedDict(sorted(tweets_categorised_by_hashtag.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True))

# limit by 10 top hashtags
if len(sorted_hashtags) > 10:
    limit_ten_hashtags = dict(itertools.islice(sorted_hashtags.items(), 10))
    # limit_ten_hashtags
    return json.dumps(limit_ten_hashtags)

return json.dumps(sorted_hashtags)
```

My question is, is it even possible to change the order, store it in a variable, and maintain that order? This video pretty much says its not possible to change the order of a dictionary https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MGD_b2w_GU4. And some of the answers I have seen only prints the desired change but will not maintain that order.

[image: response of endpoint route]

Comment: Because you aren't sending a dict, you are *serializing* a dict yo JSON, a text-based serialization format, then sending that. Have you read the documentation for `json.dump`? Notice any relevant arguments?

Comment: Also, it definitely is possible to re-order a dict, `OrderedDict` is not necessary for this on Python 3.7+ were regular dicts maintain insertion order

Comment: Actually the ordering was fine all along, but you helped me point to the right direction when you hinted it is fine server side before sending the data. It turns out that the preview on chrome always orders by alphabet and caps for presentational purposes, If I look at the response tab, everything is ordered as expected